# Angular 5 Passing form data to another component's dropdown in sync

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form (a material dialog modal) which lets the user to create an account, once the user clicks on Register button then the user stays on the same page with the username of that account that he created. The issue I am having is its getting created but its not getting updated in sync with the closing of dialog modal. Means the user should be registered and in parallel that created user value should be populated in the dropdown for better user expereince. I dont want the user to distract from the current page because if the user have entered the details and if that page is reloaded then all the data whatever he entered will be lost. So i dont want that to happen. So for that i created this below code.

```
<section class="container-fluid with-maxwidth chapter">

    <article class="article">
        <div class="box box-default">
            <div class="box-body">

                <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>

                    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
                        <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
                            <ng-template matStepLabel>Project Registration</ng-template>

                            <div class="form-group row"></div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-0 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <mat-input-container class="full-width">
                                        <input required [(ngModel)]="project.name" formControlName="nameCtrl" id="name"
                                               matInput placeholder="Project name">
                                    </mat-input-container>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Repository details -->

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-0 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <mat-input-container class="full-width">
                                        <input required [(ngModel)]="project.url" formControlName="urlCtrl" id="repo"
                                               matInput placeholder="Repository URL">
                                    </mat-input-container>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="callout1 text-muted callout-info1">
                                        <p>e.g. https://github.com/username/MyApp.git or
                                            git@github.com:username/MyApp.git.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-0 control-label">
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-select placeholder="Repository Credentials" required
                                                    [(ngModel)]="project.account.id" formControlName="typeCtrl">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.id">
                                                {{account.name}} ({{account.accountType}})
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="callout1 text-muted callout-info1">
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="javascript:;" (click)="openDialog()">Add credentials</a>
                                            <br/>
                                            Credentials are required for automatic test creation and check-in.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <mat-card-actions>
                                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
                                            class="nav-btn"
                                            [disabled]="firstFormGroup.invalid"
                                            (click)="save(stepper);">Save & Next
                                    </button>
                                </mat-card-actions>
                            </div>
<div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="col-md-0"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                      <button [disabled]="!heroForm.valid" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="create();"
                              class="btn-w-md no-margin-left">Register
                      </button>
                      <button mat-button type="button" color="primary" class="btn-w-md" (click)="onClose();">Cancel
                      </button>
                  </div>
              </div>


   </form>
                    </mat-step>
                    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    </article>
                    </section>
```

From the template's below code, here if go to other page and then come to here then the username is adding to the drop down properly. But i dont want the user to go back and forth to see whether his credentials are registered or not but instead i want to show the credentials created on the fly so that he can further move.

```
<mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-select placeholder="Repository Credentials" required
                                                    [(ngModel)]="project.account.id" formControlName="typeCtrl">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.id">
                                                {{account.name}} ({{account.accountType}})
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
```

The code for register dialog box component

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() entry: Account = new Account();
create(entry: Account) {
    this.handler.activateLoader();
    this.snackbarService.openSnackBar(this.entry.name + " registering...", "");
    this.accountService.create(entry).subscribe(results => {
      this.entry = entry;
      this.handler.hideLoader();
      if (this.handler.handle(results)) {
        return;
      }
    this.snackbarService.openSnackBar(this.entry.name + " registered successfully", "");
    this.onClose();
    // this.router.navigateByUrl('/app/projects', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
    // this.router.navigate(['/app/projects/new'])); 
    this.router.navigate(['/app/projects/new']);
    }, error => {
      this.handler.hideLoader();
      this.handler.error(error);
    });
  }

  onClose(){
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

This is where i have written the service:

```
import { Account } from './../models/project.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {

  private serviceUrl = '/api/v1/accounts';
  private entry = new Subject<Object>();
  entry$ = this.entry.asObservable();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  create(entry: Account): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, entry);
  }

  emitAccount(entry){
    this.entry.next();
  }

}
```

I want the user to be on the same page and should update the dropdown with latest results. How is that possible? Could you please suggest me? What i have done wrong with my code.

Thanks.

Comment: As your code is not much clear as to where create function is getting called and why @input is used and how emitAccount is integrated, I take wild guess that you try using BehaviorSubject instead of Subject.

Comment: Hi Pranay, See the HTML i have added the create function.

Answer (score 0):

create Service:

```
let newEntry = this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, entry);
emitAccount(newEntry);
return newEntry;
```

Register Component:

```
entry$.subscribe(updateAccount => {
accounts.push(updateAccount)
}
```

Comment: Hi Pranay, where is this accounts & updateAccount came from? Could you please clarify?

Comment: accounts is your array/list which you are binding on html side and updateAccount (its just an alias) is the new entry you are receiving as a return object from your httppost.

Answer (score -1):

So to check .. it's about this section?

```
            <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.id">
                                        {{account.name}} ({{account.accountType}})
                                    </mat-option>
```

BEcause I don't see anything in your code repopulating accounts array after registering.

I can't see where you bind the accounts array.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, so i want to repopulate the accounts array. So how to achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: What you can do is, so in the Account service have an event (Subject) ready you trigger in the create() function. Then in your main component (probably where you call the openDialog() function) , you subscribe on that event. So when that event triggers, you can then do the steps to get the data and populate the accounts array.

Comment: so for example in the account service have onNewUserCreated = new Subject<any>();

Comment: And in the create() you trigger onNewUserCreated .. and on your main component you subscribe on onNewUserCreated

Comment: I kinda gave you the answer .. you please try it :) .. you need 1) Setup a variable in your service as type Subject(). 2) Trigger that subject in the create() function when it's successfull. 3) Subscribe on that subject on your main component

Comment: Article that helped me is : http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject